# How do I go to the next item in Drop Downlist on Button Click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

below is my code. this selects the first but 1 and it does not go again

```
Dim idx As Integer = Me.Dpdtokens.SelectedIndex
        If idx <> Me.Dpdtokens.SelectedIndex - 1 Then
           
            Me.Dpdtokens.SelectedIndex = idx + 1

        Else
            Me.Dpdtokens.SelectedIndex = 0
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If cboHotel.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        ' user has selected item, increase by 1
        If cboHotel.SelectedIndex < cboHotel.Items.Count - 1 Then
            cboHotel.SelectedIndex += 1
        End If
    Else
        ' no selection at all - lets start at 0
        cboHotel.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

So, if user not selected anything (and you allowed that, then selected index is -1. However, by default it will start out with the first item as being selected.

It also not clear what/why your logic grabs selected index, and then on next link checks if they are different? (they can't be).

Edit: ==============================

Also, it not been shown how the dropdown/combo box is being loaded up with values.

For example, I have this on page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadCombo()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadCombo()

    Dim rstHotels As DataTable = New DataTable

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT ID, HotelName, City, Province FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstHotels.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    cboHotel.DataSource = rstHotels
    cboHotel.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Note VERY careful how I check for is postback. And thus do not re-load the combo box over and over. If you re-load and re-bind the combo box each time on page load, then the selected index etc. will be lost.

and the above advice applies to gridview, listbox etc. In other words, while we have a page load event, we only want to load up controls on FIRST page load. Since all other buttons and events ALSO WILL trigger page load over and over for each post-back, then if we change the index of the combo box, but re-load each time, then the index location will be lost.

Hence, in general, loading up of such controls like combo box, gridviews etc. should only occur one time, and the first time the page loads.
This goal is achieved by checking and using a If Not IsPostBack code stub in the page on-load event.

Comment: thanks but am facing same problem. but my html code is in an update panel i don't know if that can have effect on it

Comment: It should not matter. But you could well place the button in the update panel . However, if the button is outside the update panel, it does a full page post back anyway, so it should not matter again. However if the button click is in a DIFFERNT update panel then the combo box - that will not work.

Comment: My entire page is in an update panel meaning all my elements are inside an update panel. I have also tried setting the button as postback triga but still

Comment: Update panel not the issue then. You MUST always on first page load check if not IsPostBack then "code to load grid, combo box etc." goes here. You can't in fact build ANY kind of working web page if you break this rule (that is to load up controls, grids, combo box etc. on first page load - so loading up of controls code MUST be placed in that page load If Not IsPostBack then code stub. This is required for all web page designs - even when using update panels. So "not working" needs more information, but sounds like combo gets re-loaded each time and not only is ispostback = false stub.

Comment: You have to post at least the markup that has the button and the dropdown list. And show how the combo box is being loaded up with choices.

Comment: See my code edit  - I explain the page load issue, and how to write code to load up the combo box, but not lose the settings or changes you make to the combo box. (simple only load up the combo box one time as per example code).

Comment: thanks so much for your time  the data is being loaded on form_Load but infact it escaped me to have added if not IsPostBack. now it is working perfectly thanks ones again

Comment: It is a common problem - and oh so often posters here ask why is my grid not selecting etc. So, keep in mind that a simple button click will always fire page load. So, load up grids, combo etc. in a REAL first page load event. If you don't, then anything you enter into that combo or grid view will get blown out on each new page load.

Comment: noted please thanks again